# Is there a Python GUI Builder that can provide widgets like this example?

Tags: python

Note the curved corners on the widgets. This example was done with a C# gui builder.

[image]

Comment: I guess you can use [tkinter canvases](http://effbot.org/tag/Tkinter.Canvas).

Comment: Artemis - I have been very busy and just now got back to this. I will see what I can do with tkinter canvases and let you know. I am hopeful.